# Images are not resizing

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am making a gallery website with materializedcss. I am trying to make it so 4 images show up on each row, with them not looking so big, however with what I have written, all the images are displaying in their full size, rather than being minimzed to then be expanded via the materialboxed class. I am unsure if it is a problem with the css I have written, or through the materialboxed class from materialized, but from the jsfiddle, it seems like it is a problem with their class.

https://jsfiddle.net/ptfbkwre/

https://materializecss.com/media.html

```
<div id="recent">
      <div class="imagetab-grid">
        <img class="materialboxed" src="img/xjErLux.jpg" data-caption="short description. idk. image looks cool!">
      </div>
      <div class="imagetab-grid">
        <img class="materialboxed" src="img/07xoCEp.jpg" data-caption="short description. idk. image looks cool!">
      </div>
      <div class="imagetab-grid">
        <img class="materialboxed" src="img/903IrFQ.jpg" data-caption="short description. idk. image looks cool!">
      </div>
    </div>

.imagetab-grid{
  width: 25%;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.imagetab-grid>img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please tell me do you want to make a grid container, flex container or do it with floats?

Comment: a grid container I think so that there's 4 images per row, in addition to the image size being scaled down significantly.

Comment: @wwawkll122 Since you already accepted other answer, here is code to grid display image gallery https://jsfiddle.net/wba5unmL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey hope this helps I have forked your Fiddle and modified a little bit and attached the code here.

```css
.imagetab-grid {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
}

.imagetab-grid img {
  width: 100%;
}

/* Clearfix (clear floats) */
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div id="recent" class="row">
  <div class="imagetab-grid">
    <img class="materialboxed" src="https://dikxrpw3rdepo.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/tbs2_ost_interior_2560x1440.png" data-caption="short description. idk. image looks cool!">
  </div>
  <div class="imagetab-grid">
    <img class="materialboxed" src="https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/940586530515504757/CDDE77CB810474E1C07B945E40AE4713141AFD76/" data-caption="short description. idk. image looks cool!">
  </div>
  <div class="imagetab-grid">
    <img class="materialboxed" src="https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/940586530515504757/CDDE77CB810474E1C07B945E40AE4713141AFD76/" data-caption="short description. idk. image looks cool!">
  </div>
  <div class="imagetab-grid">
    <img class="materialboxed" src="https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/940586530515504757/CDDE77CB810474E1C07B945E40AE4713141AFD76/" data-caption="short description. idk. image looks cool!">
  </div>
  <div class="imagetab-grid">
    <img class="materialboxed" src="https://preppywallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/header2.jpg" data-caption="short description. idk. image looks cool!">
  </div>

</div>
```

[Reference here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_images_side_by_side)

Comment: Nice one! There is one problem, OP wanted a grid container.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for, I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do this the [Materialize](https://materializecss.com/media-css.html) way rather than the generic css way, use the provided `.reponsive-img` utility class to force images to respect the width of their containers:

```
<img src="" alt="" class="responsive-img">
```

Also, you can easily achieve a 4 column grid using the provided grid system - that's what it's for:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6 l3">
      <img src="" alt="" class="responsive-img">
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m6 l3">
      <img src="" alt="" class="responsive-img">
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m6 l3">
      <img src="" alt="" class="responsive-img">
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m6 l3">
      <img src="" alt="" class="responsive-img">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/GRoKqKb).